# how to parse more complex human-oriented text output to machine-friently style?

Tags: json, jq, text-processing

This is the question about how to parse "unparseable" output into json, or to something easily consumable as json. This is "little" bit behind trivial stuff, so I'd like to know, how do you solve these things in principle, it's not about this specific example only. But example:

We have this command, which shows data about audio inputs:

```
pacmd list-sink-inputs
```

it prints something like this:

```
2 sink input(s) available.
    index: 144
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    flags: 
    state: RUNNING
    sink: 4 <alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.0.analog-stereo>
    volume: front-left: 15728 /  24% / -37.19 dB,   front-right: 15728 /  24% / -37.19 dB
            balance 0.00
    muted: no
    current latency: 70.48 ms
    requested latency: 210.00 ms
    sample spec: float32le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    resample method: copy
    module: 13
    client: 245 <MPlayer>
    properties:
        media.name = "UNREAL! Tetris Theme on Violin and Guitar-TnDIRr9C83w.webm"
        application.name = "MPlayer"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "32"
        application.process.id = "1543"
        application.process.user = "mmucha"
        application.process.host = "vbDesktop"
        application.process.binary = "mplayer"
        application.language = "C"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "720184179caa46f0a3ce25156642f7a0"
        application.process.session_id = "2"
        module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:MPlayer"
    index: 145
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    flags: 
    state: RUNNING
    sink: 4 <alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.0.analog-stereo>
    volume: front-left: 24903 /  38% / -25.21 dB,   front-right: 24903 /  38% / -25.21 dB
            balance 0.00
    muted: no
    current latency: 70.50 ms
    requested latency: 210.00 ms
    sample spec: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    resample method: speex-float-1
    module: 13
    client: 251 <MPlayer>
    properties:
        media.name = "Trombone Shorty At Age 13 - 2nd Line-k9YUi3UhEPQ.webm"
        application.name = "MPlayer"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "32"
        application.process.id = "2831"
        application.process.user = "mmucha"
        application.process.host = "vbDesktop"
        application.process.binary = "mplayer"
        application.language = "C"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "720184179caa46f0a3ce25156642f7a0"
        application.process.session_id = "2"
        module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:MPlayer"
```

very nice. But we don't want to show user all of this, we just want to show index (id of input), application.process.id, application.name and media.name, in some reasonable format. It would be great to parse it *somehow* to json, but even if I preprocess it somehow, the `jq` is way beyond my capabilities and quite complex. I tried multiple approaches using jq, with regex or without, but I wasn't able to finish it. And I guess we cannot rely on order or presence of all fields.

I was able to get the work "done", but it's messy, inefficient, and namely expects no semicolons in media name or app name. Not acceptable solution, but this is the only thing I was able to bring to the "end".

incorrect solution:

```
cat exampleOf2Inputs | 
grep -e "index: \|application.process.id = \|application.name = \|media.name = " | 
sed "s/^[ \t]*//;s/^\([^=]*\) = /\1: /" | 
tr "\n" ";" | 
sed "s/$/\n/;s/index:/\nindex:/g" | 
tail -n +2 | 
while read A; do 
index=$(echo $A|sed "s/^index: \([0-9]*\).*/\1/");
pid=$(echo $A|sed 's/^.*application\.process\.id: \"\([0-9]*\)\".*$/\1/'); 
appname=$(echo $A|sed 's/^.*application\.name: \"\([^;]*\)\".*$/\1/'); 
medianame=$(echo $A|sed 's/^.*media\.name: \"\([^;]*\)\".*$/\"\1\"/'); 

echo "pid=$pid index=$index appname=$appname medianame=$medianame"; 
done
```

~ I grepped the interessant part, replaced newlines with semicolon, split to multiple lines, and just extract the data multiple times using sed. Crazy.

Here the output is:

```
pid=1543 index=144 appname=MPlayer medianame="UNREAL! Tetris Theme on Violin and Guitar-TnDIRr9C83w.webm"
pid=2831 index=145 appname=MPlayer medianame="Trombone Shorty At Age 13 - 2nd Line-k9YUi3UhEPQ.webm"
```

which is easily convertable to any format, but the question was about json, so to:

```
[
  {
    "pid": 1543,
    "index": 144,
    "appname": "MPlayer",
    "medianame": "UNREAL! Tetris Theme on Violin and Guitar-TnDIRr9C83w.webm"
  },
  {
    "pid": 2831,
    "index": 145,
    "appname": "MPlayer",
    "medianame": "Trombone Shorty At Age 13 - 2nd Line-k9YUi3UhEPQ.webm"
  }
]
```

Now I'd like to see, please, how are these things done correctly.

Comment: How does one determine where the start and end of the "objects" are? There's no clear indicator that the first object ended. We can observe that the first instance of a repeated key (`index` here) might seem reasonable, but that's way too ambiguous.

Comment: @JeffMercado I apologize. It's a rendering issue. Please check this paste-bin AND click raw. Without raw it's still rendered incorrectly. https://pastebin.com/xXe1a4es  But in principle first line of each entry is: "index: [0-9]+"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input is as reasonable as shown in the Q, the following  approach that only uses jq should be possible.

An invocation along the following lines is assumed:

```
jq -nR -f parse.jq input.txt
```

```
def parse:
  def interpret:
    if . == null then .
    elif startswith("\"") and endswith("\"")
    then  .[1:-1]
    else tonumber? // .
    end;
  (capture( "(?<key>[^\t:= ]*)(: | = )(?<value>.*)" ) // null)
  | if . then .value = (.value | interpret) else . end
;

# Construct one object for each "segment"  
def construct(s): 
  [ foreach (s, 0) as $kv (null;
      if $kv == 0 or $kv.index
      then .complete = .accumulator | .accumulator = $kv
      else .complete = null | .accumulator += $kv
      end;
      .complete // empty ) ]
;


construct(inputs | parse | select(.) | {(.key):.value})
| map( {pid: .["application.process.id"],
        index,
        appname: .["application.name"],
        medianame: .["media.name"]} )
```

With the example input, the output would be:

```
[
  {
    "pid": "1543",
    "index": 144,
    "appname": "MPlayer",
    "medianame": "UNREAL! Tetris Theme on Violin and Guitar-TnDIRr9C83w.webm"
  },
  {
    "pid": "2831",
    "index": 145,
    "appname": "MPlayer",
    "medianame": "Trombone Shorty At Age 13 - 2nd Line-k9YUi3UhEPQ.webm"
  }
]
```

#### Brief explanation

`parse` parses one line. It assumes that whitespace (blank and tab characters) on each line before the key name can be ignored.

`construct` is responsible for grouping the lines (presented as a stream of key-value single-key objects) corresponding to a particular value of “index”. It produces an array of objects, one for each value of “index”.

Comment: just wow. Well it does not work for me either, as only index is extracted. I'd suspect, that it's just by incorrect formatting of original question (made by stackoverflow). I knew that jq is powerful, but this is beyond my expectation. I'd like to fix that mistake somewhere, but ... I totally, and by that I mean totally, entirelly, don't understand it. The input, execution and response is present here(please click raw! to see correct formatting): https://pastebin.com/bLTK9DUr

Comment: could you explain the details of your solution?

Comment: For a brief explanation, please see the added section. The given solution assumes your jq has `inputs` and that jq has been invoked as shown.

Comment: Thanks for our effort.I was trying to decipher this using manual,but that's impossible. I can understand everyting in "jq tutorial" on jq page fluently.I cannot find where your script starts :D The learning curve from tutorial to your usage requires usage of jetpack :) ...ad "the given solution assumest your jq has inputs" — yeah, it seems, that first object you work with is `inputs`.No idea what it is or how to start. Tried this: `echo '{"a":"b"}' | jq -f <(echo 'inputs | parse | select(.)')` as smallest portion of your code—fails.If you can share any learning material,it would be appreciated

Comment: `echo test | jq -nR inputs` works. Still trying ;) wish me luck! (any study material still apreciated ;) )

Comment: ok, I think I finally undestand your code structure and jq a little more. I think I can fight this and learn from it. It still does not match other indices than index, but I think I should be able to fix it...

Comment: OK, I have fix which made it working for me: replace `(capture( "(?<key>[^:= ]*)(: | = )(?<value>.*)" ) // null)` with `(capture( "[ \t]*(?<key>[^:= ]*)(: | = )(?<value>.*)" ) // null)`. I still don't understand construct method, though. What is `(s,0)` in `foreach (s, 0) as $kv`? I cannot find it documented anywhere ...

Comment: marking this as correct answer. If you [anyone] read my comments, I had to fix answer as stackoverflow misinterpreted the original answer, which is thus not on-par with actually produced output of given command, but the fix is rather subtle. Syntax isn't very easy at first, but it's a good way how to learn more about jq. Thanks @peak!

Comment: The tutorial is really just an introduction to reading the manual.  See also the wiki for supplementary materials: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki

Comment: Initial whitespace (tabs and blanks) is now ignored. Re (s,0), you might like to look at "A Stream-oriented Introduction to jq" [https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq]

Comment: Thanks, I'll read it! Btw. I had my own theory what `(s,0)` is and had suspition, that it does nothing and that it worked even without it, but words "stream-oriented introduction" raised some suspition in my brain, followed by feeling, that I might not get whole output in that scenario. So I retest. And brain was correct. And now I udnerstand. The `(s,0)` acts as a trigger for cleaning buffer at the end of input :D Aach, I finally get it all.

Comment: Very nice, quite hacky though. Not sure how long it would take me to write it from scratch. It definitely requires completely different mindset than traditional imperative programming. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "correctly", but this is what I'd do:

```sh
pacmd list-sink-inputs | awk '
    BEGIN { print "[" }
    function print_record() {
        if (count++) {
            print "  {"
            printf "    %s,\n", print_number("pid")
            printf "    %s,\n", print_number("index")
            printf "    %s,\n", print_string("appname")
            printf "    %s\n",  print_string("medianame")
            print "  },"
        }
        delete record
    }
    function print_number(key) { return sprintf("\"%s\": %d", key, record[key]) }
    function print_string(key) { return sprintf("\"%s\": \"%s\"", key, record[key]) }
    function get_quoted_value() {
        if (match($0, /[^"]+"$/))
            return substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH-1)
        else
            return "?"
    }
    $1 == "index:" { print_record(); record["index"] = $2 }
    $1 == "application.process.id" { record["pid"]       = get_quoted_value() }
    $1 == "application.name"       { record["appname"]   = get_quoted_value() }
    $1 == "media.name"             { record["medianame"] = get_quoted_value() }
    END { print_record(); print "]" }
' | 
  tac | awk '/},$/ && !seen++ {sub(/,$/,"")} 1' | tac
```

where the `tac|awk|tac` line removes the trailing comma from the *last* JSON object in the list.

```
[
  {
    "pid": 1543,
    "index": 144,
    "appname": "MPlayer",
    "medianame": "UNREAL! Tetris Theme on Violin and Guitar-TnDIRr9C83w.webm"
  },
  {
    "pid": 2831,
    "index": 145,
    "appname": "MPlayer",
    "medianame": "Trombone Shorty At Age 13 - 2nd Line-k9YUi3UhEPQ.webm"
  }
]
```

Comment: I apologize, but there is probably some error, maybe due to formatting here? I don't know how I could fix this. I'd like to learn awk to understand your example, and I will, but at this moment I don't have sufficient knowledge to fix this solution: https://pastebin.com/Rp2r6x72

Comment: Oops, I had an unmatched open brace. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You could just pipe your output into:

```sh
sed -E '
  s/pid=([0-9]+) index=([0-9]+) appname=([^ ]+) medianame=(.*)/{"pid": \1, "index": \2, "appname": "\3", "medianame": \4},/
  1s/^/[/
  $s/,$/]/
' | jq .
```

Comment: I apologize, but this does not work. Details shown here: https://pastebin.com/p1wrYMdF

Comment: (please click raw button, to be sure you see correct formatting)

Comment: This is meant to be applied to the end of *your* pipeline that produces the two line output.